# Windows App Certification Kit does not launch due to error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, app-certification-kit

I am unable to launch the Windows App Certification Kit to test my Windows Phone 8.1 app on the same machine I use to develop the app (running Windows 8.1 and VS 2013 Ultimate Update 4). The error message I get is:

> The UI workflow of Windows App Certification Kit is not supported on
>   this OS version.

I have tried to launch the kit via the command line (with administrator privileges) and via Visual Studio, but I get the same error.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: This question looks like it should be a bug report directed to whoever sold you the software. It does not look like something programming can solve.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The kit is installed as part of the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK. Given that I think this question is within the realm of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions about using programming tools to program are naturally on-topic. This question is about using programming tools to get error messages that cannot be fixed by programming. Although VS 2013 is a programming tool, a question about where to buy it, how to install it or what its EULA actually says would similarly be off-topic.

Comment: UWP certification kit on Server 2016 giving the same message, even though VS has full functionality etc.
Concerning on/off topic, that a programmer should start an account on some other forum, and I really don't know which may be more suitable, seems quite unfriendly, after all SO hosts questions on all stages of software development, testing should be included, in my opinion at least.

Comment: I also get this error running the Windows 10 SDK on Windows Server 2012 R2.